# Adding a Face Tracker Texture over Camera Effect

Tags: filter, effect, spark-ar-studio

Hope everyone is having a good day. I recently built a filter with a camera effect over it but i’d also like to add a plane tracker on top of it (a company slogan texture image). I added in my Facetracker > Plane > add Material and it shows up on my preview screen (the development grid) but it doesn’t appear on a preview of the filter (mockup screen with my face). I am not sure why this is happening and I don’t know how to fix it.

If anyone has any has any solutions it would be very helpful. I am open all suggestions.

Thanks so much!

[Face Tracker shows up on my grid but not my actual effect/filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK3hQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use this: Facetracker > Canvas> Rectangle > add Material

Click on Rectangle and on the right panel, click on the 100% on the Width and select Fill Width & the same on height but Fill Height

It isn't appearing as planes are for 3D materials for positioning these 3D materials anywhere in the scene

A rectangle provides a space to apply 2D materials and must be a child of a Canvas

Also, You can't have a plane tracker under a face  tracker as the plane is an infinite horizontal tool